# What is the Base R equivalent of this dplyr group_by code?

Tags: r, dplyr, tapply

[The R4DS book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-order) has the following code block:

```
library(tidyverse)
by_age2 <- gss_cat %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  count(age, marital) %>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))
```

Is there a simple equivalent to this code in base R? The `filter` can be replaced with `gss_cat[!is.na(gss_cat$age),]`, but after that I run in to trouble. It's clearly a job for `by`, `tapply`, or `aggregate`, but I've not been able to find the right way. `by(gss_2, with(gss_2, list(age, marital)), length)` is a step in the right direction, but the output is awful.

Comment: Try `proportions(table(subset(gss_cat, complete.cases(age), select = c(age, marital))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `proportions` on the `table` output after `subset`ting to remove the `NA` (`complete.cases`) and `select`ing the columns

The data is from `forcats` package.  So, load the package and get the data

```
library(forcats)
data(gss_cat)
```

Use the `table/proportions` as mentioned above

```
by_age2_base <- proportions(table(subset(gss_cat, complete.cases(age), 
       select = c(age, marital))), 1)
```

-output

```
head(by_age2_base, 3)
    marital
age    No answer Never married   Separated    Divorced     Widowed     Married
  18 0.000000000   0.978021978 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.021978022
  19 0.000000000   0.939759036 0.000000000 0.012048193 0.004016064 0.044176707
  20 0.000000000   0.904382470 0.003984064 0.007968127 0.000000000 0.083665339
```

-compare with the OP's output

```
head(by_age2, 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   age [2]
    age marital           n   prop
  <int> <fct>         <int>  <dbl>
1    18 Never married    89 0.978 
2    18 Married           2 0.0220
3    19 Never married   234 0.940
```

---

If we need the output in 'long' format, convert the `table` to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`

```
by_age2_base_long <- subset(as.data.frame(by_age2_base), Freq > 0)
```

---

Or another option is `aggregate/ave` (use `R 4.1.0`)

```
subset(gss_cat, complete.cases(age), select = c(age, marital)) |> 
    {\(dat) aggregate(cbind(n = age) ~ age + marital, 
      data = dat, FUN = length)}() |> 
   transform(prop = ave(n, age, FUN = \(x) x/sum(x)))
```